# How to query objects with points in fields in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I query to find a register like find where X2016.may = 32863. My solution work for geting the 'RFC' register.

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"RFC" : "AAA020211GV8"})
```

But it doesn't work for querying the other data, does not find any records and returns:

```
db.getCollection('input').find({"X2016.may" : 32863})
"Fetched 0 record(s) in 14ms"
```

This is a sample document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5756f39de030aeae54a72b6a"),
    "RFC" : "AAA020211GV8",
    "X2016.may" : 32863,
    "X2016.abr" : 34071,
    "X2016.mar" : 23793,
    "X2016.feb" : 86647,
    "X2016.ene" : 30864,
    "X2015.dic" : 84694,
    "X2015.nov" : 80124,
    "X2015.oct" : 97883,
    "X2015.sep" : 29913,
    "X2015.ago" : 57526,
    "X2015.jul" : 82927,
    "X2015.jun" : 34261,
    "X2015.may" : 98638,
    "X2015.abr" : 64738,
    "X2015.mar" : 45826,
    "X2015.feb" : 78345,
    "X2015.ene" : 75287,
    "X2014.dic" : 46050,
    "X2014.nov" : 86394,
    "X2014.oct" : 54328,
    "X2014.sep" : 65698,
    "X2014.ago" : 68757,
    "X2014.jul" : 30403,
    "X2014.jun" : 43622
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you insert the data? Mongo won't allow such as you can't have the dot character `.` in field names

Comment: I made a mongo connect with R, was a batch upload with the package rmongodb. The columns names was from my dataframe previous to make the bson file. Substituting the point for a different character (i.e "_" or "-") may be a solution?

Comment: I made the solution, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to substitute the "." for a "_" with the next function before making the mmongo.insert.batch() to uploading the data to mongo.

```
names(df) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(df))
```